# Automatically resolving dependencies in laravel without passing parameters to constructor?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel search helper, my helper class needs laravel request object and another class called QueryFilters, I want to inlcude these dependencies INSIDE the class itself so I don't have to pass them as parameters:

This helper class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;
use App\Filters\QueryFilters;
use App\Filters\Filterable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class Search
{


    public function __construct(Request $request, QueryFilters $filters)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filters = $filters;
    }

    public static function search( $model, $relationships = [] )
    {
        $requestModel = $request->model;

        $model = app("App\Model\{$requestModel}");

        $results = $model::search($request->input('search'), '')->get(); 

        if(!$results->isEmpty())
        {
            $ids = implode(',', $results->pluck('id')->toArray());
            $filters->merge(['whereIn' => $ids]);    
        }

        $results = $model::filter($filters)->with($relationships)->paginate(10);

        return $results; 
    }


}
```

In my controler method when I instantiate the search class it tells me I need to pass two arguments to the class,  is there a way to automatically add these dependencies INSIDE my class so I don't need to pass them each time? I thought putting them in my class constructor would automatically resolve them for me but obviously that's not the case:

```
$search = new Search();
$products = $search->search('Product', ['productcategory']);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the dependencies to be resolved automatically, you have to create a method and pass the `Search class` as an argument.

```
public function searchProducts(Search $search)
{
    $products = $search->search('Product', ['productcategory']);
}
```

If the search class itself only depends upon [other concrete classes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#zero-configuration-resolution), the class can be resolved automatically.
For more information you can also refer to this [Laracasts Episode](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/39).

Answer (score 0):

You can use: resolve() 
`$search = resolve(Search::class);` 
`$products = $search->search('Product', ['productcategory']);`